# JQuery - how to create nested elements with script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, nested

I have a newbie question. I want to add an element as below to document using JQuery 1.11.0. It's supposed to add a delete button and p.Name to the page.

```
 <li id="@pv.Key@p.Id">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconDelete', showLabel: false"> Remove
         <script type="dojo/connect" event="onClick" args="evt">
             removeCC("@p.Id","@pv.Key");
         </script>
     </div>
           @p.Name 
 </li>
```

So i did as below, and the result is a bullet followed by "Remove". It's supposed to be a bullet and a dojo delete button followed by a name in variable value.

```
function filtersubmit(value, orgId) {
    var scpt = $("<script/>", { type: "dojo/connect", event: "onClick", args: "evt", html: "removeCC('" + value + "','" + orgId + "');" });
    var div = $("<div/>", {
        'data-dojo-type': "dijit/form/Button",
        'data-dojo-props': "iconClass:'dijitIconDelete', showLabel: false"
    }).text("Remove").append(scpt);
    var item = $("<li/>", { id: orgId + value, content: value }).append(div);

   $('#' + orgId).append(item)
}
```

Please help me figure out what was wrong with it. Thank you so much

Comment: It appears that you're never actually using the `div` variable you made.

Comment: Thanks. It's a typo. It's supposed to be item.append(div).  The html code block is working, but the JQuery is not working.